# Sticky is not defined using Laravel Mix

Tags: npm, webpack, laravel-mix

Trying to use Laravel Mix to include node_modules for my application. Not very experienced with this

I'm trying to include sticky.js but keep getting the message in console:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: Sticky is not defined*

Here is my webpack file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/vendor.js', 'public/js')
.combine([
  'resources/js/appOptions.js',
  'resources/js/scripts.bundle.js',
], 'public/js/scripts.bundle.js')
.copy('resources/js/pages/*.js', 'public/js/pages')
.copy('resources/js/plugins/', 'public/js/plugins')
.sass('resources/sass/vendor.scss', 'public/css/')
.copy('resources/css/style.bundle.css', 'public/css')
.copy('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
.copy('resources/css/pages/*.css', 'public/css/pages')
.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      modules: [
        'node_modules'
      ],
      alias: {
        jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
      }
    }
});

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
    mix.disableNotifications();
}
```

My vendor.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'sticky-js';
import 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
import 'jquery-validation';
```

and scripts.blade.php file which is called in other blade files:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/scripts.bundle.js') }}"></script>
```

I've checked to see if jQuery is loading and it appears to be, given i also get the following message:

> *jQuery.Deferred exception: Sticky is not defined ReferenceError: Sticky is not defined*

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to assign it to global object like below:

```
window.Sticky = require('sticky-js');
```

PS:
I don't see any jQuery inclusion in your vendor. Try to add this to your vendor.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Make sure you've included jquery and sticky as dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: I actually ended up doing these exact two things 15 minutes after i posted this. Even though it works, good to know I did it right too. Thanks!

Comment: @SeánMcCabe Great!